# Mac OS Error: Could not find or load main class com.ef.Parser

Tags: java, spring, macos, intellij-idea

I have a Spring boot app and I made the JAR out of it with the command

```
mvn package
```

The JAR file goes in the `target` folder namely `parser.jar`

[image]

The Spring boot main class is provided,

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
//@ComponentScan({"com.ef"})
@EntityScan("com.ef.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ef.repository")
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.ef"}, exclude = JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Parser implements CommandLineRunner {

    public Parser() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Parser.class);
        application.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {


        Options options = new Options();

        Option start = new Option("startDate", "startDate", true, "Start date");
        start.setRequired(true);
        options.addOption(start);

        Option duration = new Option("duration", "duration", true, "duration");
        duration.setRequired(true);
        options.addOption(duration);

        Option threshold = new Option("threshold", "threshold", true, "threshold");
        threshold.setRequired(true);
        options.addOption(threshold);

        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
        HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
        CommandLine cmd;

        try {
            cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            formatter.printHelp("utility-name", options);

            System.exit(1);
            return;
        }

        String startDate = cmd.getOptionValue("startDate");
        String dur = cmd.getOptionValue("duration");
        String thers = cmd.getOptionValue("threshold");

        System.out.println(startDate);
        System.out.println(dur);
        System.out.println(thers);


        exit(0);
    }
}
```

I run the command in the IntelliJ terminal,

```
java -cp target/"parser.jar" com.ef.Parser --startDate=2000-10-21.21:55:36 --duration=hourly --threshold=100
```

and, I'm in the project folder of `Mac OS`, `/Users/XYZ/IdeaProjects/LogParser`

I would like to strip off the values from the parameters `startDate`, `duration` and the `threshold` and print them in the console. However, I get the message like `Error: Could not find or load main class com.ef.Parser`

What is the issue here?

`Update`

As someone suggested about the double quote, I have tried without using them and still doesn't help. I will be up for other suggestions.

`pwd` command result: `/Users/XYZ/IdeaProjects/LogParser`

`ls` command result prints:

```
LICENSE                 Log.txt                 README.txt              hello-springboot.iml    pom.xml                 src                     target
```

Updated the `POM` file to reach the main class,

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>parser</finalName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.ef.Parser</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I still don't help though

## I have tried with very simple Spring boot template and still, it doesn't work

Comment: In the same IntelliJ terminal, what is the result of the `ls` and `pwd` commands?

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens I have provided the outputs in the updated question

Comment: did you solved this problem @Arefe if yes, can you share the solution please?